# Trained ECDL or taught ECDL

Tags: word-choice, verb-usage

Which verb is better to use:

> He **trained** ECDL to them last year.
> or
> He **taught** ECDL to them last year.

P.S:
ECDL stands for European Computer Driving License

Comment: You cannot train a method.

Comment: He was their ECDL instructor last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can teach a student.
You can teach a subject.
You can teach a subject to a student.

You can train a student.
You can train a student on a subject

But you cannot train a subject.

Comment: Interestingly, you can train computers - although they look likely to turn the tables soon.